# What is the meaning of 5:8 in an array dimension in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I would like to know this example line.

```
Dimension A(265000, 5:8)
```

, especially 5:8

I can only know this A is going to be a 2 dimension, but I would like make sure what the 5:8 is.

Is it right to understand like 265000x5, 265000x6, 265000x7, 265000x8?

Comment: Welcome. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.ease take the Welcome [tour] and eead [ask]. This informattion can be found in older questions so please always try to search first.

Comment: Also note that ypur code is not Fortran 77, but Fortran 90 or later. If you just learn from Fortran 77 materials, you won't find it. Learn modern Fortran, we have the 21st century today.

Comment: Actually, I try to read a code, which is based on Fortran77. I am just curious why that was not Fortran77 because my code follow the fortran 77 rules. for example, begin with 6 spaces, using "c" to comment..

Comment: These rules are for *fixed source form*, it does not matter if F66, F77 or F2008. The `5:8` syntax only exists in Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two dimensional array, and 5:8 means the subscripts for the second dimension have values 5, 6, 7, 8.